# Spring security tag if user is not authenticated

Tags: spring, security, tags

I use tag `<sec:authorize access="!hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')">`

maybe is other solution ?

Answer (score 6):

This code works whether user is logged in or not, and works when using Anonymous Authentication:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <!-- if user is authenticated-->
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
    <!-- if user is not authenticated-->
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous filter. Something like this:

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
  <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
</bean>
```

And then check like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')">
```

Here you can find more information: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html